data.table error: data is not stored to the initial data table
This is my code:
Transactions_DT[, {
# Identify the rows where Unique_ID is not empty and not NA
  valid_rows <- which(Unique_ID != "" | !is.na(Unique_ID))
  
# Only process if there are valid rows
  if (length(valid_rows) > 0) {
# Calculate the cumulative sum of days to add starting from the first valid row
    days_to_add <- cumsum(Period_Length[valid_rows])
    
# Adjust the starting index for days to add to correctly apply days addition
# and offset by subtracting the first Period_Length because it's included twice (once in the initial date)
    Transaction_Date[valid_rows] <- Transaction_Date[valid_rows[1]] + days(days_to_add - Period_Length[valid_rows[1]])
  }
}, by = Con_ID]

I tried then doing := instead of <- and it does not help at all and R tells me that this is not ok to do, And I think that makes sense because of the "size" of the vector so to say... No idea How to solve it.

Something is wrong here: Unique_ID != "" | !is.na(Unique_ID). Maybe it should be &?

You might consider wrapping your logic (see minor correction due to s_baldur's keen eye) in in a function as below:
f <- \(u,t,p) {
  v <- which(u != "" & !is.na(u))
  if(length(v)>0) {
    d <- cumsum(p[v])
    t[v] <- t[v[1]] + days(d - p[v[1]])
  }
  return(t)
}

Then apply your function, by Con_ID
Transactions_DT[, Transaction_Date:=f(Unique_ID, Transaction_Date, Period_Length), Con_ID]

